# Can android JobScheduler work as a replacement of RxJava?

Tags: android, rx-java, android-jobscheduler, firebase-job-dispatcher

This is a typical network call using `rxjava` (and `retrofit`). Can `JobScheduler` be used to replace this? If yes, how? Above all, is it recommended?

```
    Observable<GenericResponse> observable = someInterface.someMethod();
    observable.subscribeOn(Schedulers.io()).observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
            .subscribe(new Observer<GenericResponse>() {
                @Override
                public void onCompleted() {
                    Log.d(TAG, "Success");
                }

                @Override
                public void onError(Throwable e) {
                    Log.e(TAG, "Error: ", e);
                }

                @Override
                public void onNext(GenericResponse genericResponse) {
                    Log.d(TAG, "onNext");
                }
            });
```

Answer (score 1):

Short answer: No

Long: 
The JobScheduler API aims on creating background processes under some conditions (charging phone, network type etc...) usually when the phone is switched off. 
RxJava is a reactive library that can be used WITH JobScheduler -if you like - and anywhere in your code to facilitate how things are happening.

Answer (score 1):

Big No.
The JobScheduler API schedules job which will be executed only when certain conditions that you define is met.